# Can I forbid the Log View pop up from bottom every time I compile my project in AndroidStudio?

Tags: android, android-studio

Every time I compile project by AndroidStudio, it pops up a View like "Android DDMS" or "Run" which annoys me because I do not want to watch it but my code. Can I forbid it?

Comment: Once you have enough reputation add them to your post.

Comment: Do you mean we can not forbid the views popup?